# Redux + React Native Add product to cart not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm new to react native and i'm tryin to implement add to cart functionality using redux, It's working when pass the whole product to the cart, but that's not what i'm looking for because i have to add quantity and an input text with every product that user select, (to give the user ability to fill them before checkout).
This is the main code (Working fine while passing the whole product)

```js
const initialState = {
    cart: [],
    total: 0,
}
...
case ADD_TO_CART:
 return {
   ...state,
   cart: [action.payload, ...state.cart],
   total: state.total + action.payload.price
 }
...
```

This is what i'm trying now

```js
const initialState = {
    cart: [],
    addCart: {
      meal_id: '',
      name: '',
      price: '',
      quantity: 1,
      meal_details: ''
    },
    total: 0,
}
case ADD_TO_CART:
  return {
    ...state,
    addCart: {
     meal_id: action.payload.id,
     name: action.payload.name,
     price: action.payload.price,
     quantity: 1,
     meal_details: ''
    },
    cart: [this.addCart, ...state.cart],
    total: state.total + action.payload.price
 }
```

But it gives errors,
`this.addCart` add undefined to the cart array, I've tried `addCart` return can't find variable addCart and i use `state.addCart` it add first item as null arr and whenever i clicked on another product to add it adds the last one clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accessing the Redux state, there's no `this`. Also, you cannot access properties of an object as you're trying to changing the object, which is also the reason why your main code works but the second snippet does not. The simplest solution to fix your code will removing `addCart` from your state, since the data is equivalent to your `action.payload`, then creating the addCart object separately in the reducer.

```
const initialState = {
    cart: [],
    total: 0,
}

case ADD_TO_CART:
  let addCart = {
     meal_id: action.payload.id,
     name: action.payload.name,
     price: action.payload.price,
     quantity: 1,
     meal_details: ''
  }
  return {
    ...state,
    cart: [addCart, ...state.cart],
    total: state.total + action.payload.price
 }
```